# Adding Android Room library (jcenter gives 404 error)

Tags: android, gradle, android-room, jcenter

I'm trying to add android Room library to my project but I can't.

I followed instructions on development site but It did not work.

build file (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

build file (app):

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

def room_version = "1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:guava:$room_version"
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"}
```

then when I sync my project.

I see this errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0.
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.1.0.
Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0
Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.1.0
Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0
```

as I checked jcenter.bintray.com gives 404 error.
what should I do?

thank you

Comment: Those artifacts are in the `google()` repository, not the `jcenter()` repository. See [`maven.google.com`](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) for a list of artifacts and versions that `google()` serves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` to the list of repositories in your build.gradle file (project):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not working. system is referring to jcenter(https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/persistence/room/runtime/1.1.0/runtime-1.1.0.pom)

Comment: In my project, I have `google()` repository in `buildscript` repositories. Not sure if that makes difference. Try that just in case.

Comment: it doesn't working. I think jcenter has a problem(error 404)

Comment: I found out that I had to setup a proxy on my gradle file